# $W$-hierarchy and parameterized search problems

Tags: decision-problem, complexity-classes, search-problem, clique, parameterized-complexity

I have two related questions:

1. What are the ways to prove that a certain problem is in $W[t]$ in the W-hierarchy for parametrized complexity, except using the straight definition of boolean circuits? I mean, is there a similar classification like for the FPT class, that if there exists an algorithm which runs in a certain complexity then the problem is in $W[1]$ (for instance)?
2. If I have a **decision** problem that I know is in $FPT$ (or $W[1]$), does it mean that its matching **search** problem is also $FPT$ (/$W[1]$)? If not, how should I refer to a parametrized **search** problem? For instnace, I know that the $k-clique$ problem is in $W[1]$, then what is the correct classification of the problem of **finding** a clique of size $k$?